# Django AssertionError at /search/

Tags: django

I have an issue when I try to search for a second time. I will get the results from the first search, however, when I want to search for a different field I'm getting AssertionError. I'm not sure how can I fix this error. Any help is appreciated.

```
def search(request):
    queryset_list = Oglas.objects.order_by('-list_date')[:5]

    # keywords
    if 'keywords' in request.GET:
        keywords = request.GET['keywords']
        if keywords:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(description__icontains = keywords) 
    # Area
    if 'area' in request.GET:
        area = request.GET['area']
        if area:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(area__iexact = area)
    # rooms 
    if 'bedrooms' in request.GET:
        bedrooms = request.GET['bedrooms']
        if bedrooms:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(bedrooms__lte=bedrooms)
```

[image]

Comment: The error is self explanatory you have sliced the queryset (`[:5]`) and cannot filter further. You can move the slice to after filtering if you need.

Comment: Thank you I fixed the issue